# C - Multiple malloc's for a struct-array inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I've got a theoretical question on allocating memory for structs. Consider the following code IN THE MAIN FUNCTION:

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *descr = NULL;
    DWORD id = 0x00FFFF00;
    int start_byte = 0;
    int end_byte = 0;
    double conversion_factor = 0.0;
} CAN_ID_ENTRY;
```

I want an array of this structs, so I'm allocating a pointer to the first struct:

```
can_id_list = (CAN_ID_ENTRY **)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY));
```

And then I'm allocating memory for the first `struct can_id_list[0]`:

```
can_id_list[0] = (CAN_ID_ENTRY *)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY));
```

Now the problem is, that I don't know HOW MANY of these structs I need (because I'm reading a CSV-File and I don't know the amount of lines/entries). So I need to enlarge the struct-pointer `can_id_list` for a second one:

```
can_id_list = (CAN_ID_ENTRY **)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY));
```

And then I'm allocating the second struct `can_id_list[1]`:

```
can_id_list[1] = (CAN_ID_ENTRY *)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY));
can_id_list[1]->id = 6;
```

Obviously, this works. But why? My point is the following: Normally, malloc allocates memory in one block in the memory (without gaps). But if another malloc is done BEFORE I'm allocating memory for the next struct, there is a gap between the first and the second struct. So, why can I access the second struct via `can_id_list[1]`? Does the index [1] store the actual address of the struct, or does it just calculate the size of the struct and jumps to this address beginning on the offset of the struct-pointer `can_id_list` (-> `can_id_list+<2*sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY)`)?

Well, my real problem is, that I need to do this inside a function and therefore I need to pass the pointer of the struct to the function. But I don't know how to do this, because `can_id_list` is already a pointer ... and the changes must also be visible in the main method (that's the reason i need to use pointers).

The mentioned function is this one:

```
int load_can_id_list(char *filename, CAN_ID_ENTRY **can_id_list);
```

But is the parameter `CAN_ID_ENTRY **can_id_list` correct? And how do i pass the struct-array into this function? And how can i modify it inside??

Any help would be great!

**EDIT: Casting malloc returns - Visual Studio forces me to do that! (Because it's a C++ project i think)**

Comment: You don't cast the result of a `malloc` in C.

Comment: I don't quite follow your question, but the space that you allocate for a pointer is different from the space that you allocate for the thing pointed at. Just because pointers are contiguous in memory, it doesn't follow that they point to contiguous blocks.

Comment: What about `realloc`?

Comment: _Obviously, this works. But why?_ Because your `sizeof` is wrong and is allocating more space than a `CAN_ID_ENTRY **` requires.

Comment: @Downvoter wow, i never heard about this function! I'm gonna try it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so what would be the correct size? an integer?

Comment: `can_id_list = malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY *) * how_many_pointers_initially);` Then, after you've used up all those pointers, use `realloc` as previously mentioned.

Comment: Try it. Read [`man 3 malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for some documentation. As the saying goes: RT(F)M.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: you state in your question that this is C++ code, so change the tag from 'c' to 'c++'

Comment: Please the [tour].  Then post a [mcve] so we know what you are actually talking about.

Comment: @user3629249 nope, actually it's C code, but as soon as you working on VS, it creates a C++ project with full C support.

Comment: you need to tell visual studio that it is a C project, not a C++ project.  The easiest way is to have the extension to the file name be 'c' not 'cpp' nor 'c++`

Comment: there is ALWAYS a gap between different memory allocations.  This is because the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) modify some data structures in the heap, Those data structure elements are (usually) just before the memory address returned to your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already said, the source of your confusion is `can_id_list = (CAN_ID_ENTRY **)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY));` allocating the wrong amount of memory. It probably gave you space for a few pointers to be stored, not just one. Should be `can_id_list = (CAN_ID_ENTRY **)malloc(sizeof(CAN_ID_ENTRY*));`.

To answer the question at the end,

> But is the parameter CAN_ID_ENTRY **can_id_list correct? And how do i
>   pass the struct-array into this function? And how can i modify it
>   inside??

If you want to enlarge the size of the array within another function, you need to pass `CAN_ID_ENTRY*** pr` so you can set `*ptr = realloc(...)` inside as needed. Realloc may give you the new chunk of memory at a different address, so you can't simply pass in a `CAN_ID_ENTRY** ptr` then do `realloc(ptr)`. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm